# How to obtain $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ from $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac{-\ln(1-x)}{x} \, dx $

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, power-series

\begin{align}
& \int_0^1 \frac{-\ln(1-x)}{x} \, dx = \int_0^1 1+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3} + \frac{x^3}{4}+\cdots \, dx \\[8pt]
= {} &\left[1+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}+\frac{x^3}{4} + \cdots \right]_0^1 = 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1^2}{3} + \frac{1^3}{4}+\cdots-1
\end{align}

I think I did something wrong, I thought I could just plug $x=1$ into the series, but it is wrong, it is a harmonic series truncated at 1. The correct solution should be the Basel problem $1+\dfrac{1}{2^2}+\dfrac{1}{3^2} + \dfrac{1}{4^2} + \cdots = \dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$

Basically, result just claim that the above integral is equal to $\displaystyle\int_0^1 -\log(1-x) \, dx$, which is impossible.

Also, is there a generalization of the integral for $\zeta(4), \zeta(6), \zeta(8)$. I guess they are related to the dilogarithm function or even polylogarithm function, am I correct?

Comment: You haven't integrate your integrand.

Comment: I was such a careless moron, thank you! I guess that's because I lost sleep because I keep thinking about and doing math.

Answer (score 1):

$-\ln(1-x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}$ for $x \in [0,1)$, so after dividing by $x$ you get $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{n}$ which is the series you wrote inside the integral. But then you didn't do the term by term integration, which is how the squares are introduced in the denominator to make the connection to $\zeta(2)$.